# Eclipse, shortcuts for effective text editing

Tags: eclipse, text, ide, editor, shortcut

What are some useful eclipse shortcuts for vim like text editing experience? For example, how do I append to the end of line, insert in the beginning, add new line above, or change the word under cursor? I know I could use vim plugin, but I want know which shortcuts eclipse provides natively.

Please share your eclipse power use shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can find 102 shortcuts at https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see All Shortcuts here:

```
Window\Preferences\General\Keys
```

To edit the shortcut:

- Click on that command
- Edit in Binding.
- Click Apply.
  Hope it's helpful.